# Parabola and a line

Tags: geometry

if m varies then find the range of c for which the line $y=mx + c$ touches the parabola $y^2 = 8(x+2)$ .

I tried Put the value $y = mx + c in$ the parabola equation and then done $D = 0$ or $D>0 $

I am getting $16/(m^2 + 8m) >0 $

But in this , how do I neglect m

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Migration to mathematics.stackexchange.com is necessary.

Comment: Extremely Sorry , wrong post

Answer (score 4):

It's just a hint, substituting $y=mx+c$ in the equation of parabola $y^2=8(x+2)$, one should get $$m^2x^2+(2mc-8)x+c^2-16=0$$ now, the given line will be tangent to the parabola iff the above quadratic equation has equal roots i.e. discriminant $\Delta=B^2-4AC=0$ hence, $$(2mc-8)^2-4(m^2)(c^2-16)=0$$
or $$2m^2-mc+2=0$$ 
now, you need an additional condition to find $c$ by eliminating $m$